# How can I speed up the query?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

How can I speed up this query?

```
 l_string varchar2(200);
 /* parameter string */
 l_string := ':27.07.2015:10.07.2015:23.07.2015:01.08.2015:'; 

 select  t3.*
  from  table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
 where  t1.col1 = t2.col2 
   and  t2.col3 = t3.col4
   and  (instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col1, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col2, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col3, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col4, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col5, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col6, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col7, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col8, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 OR
         instr(l_string, ':' || to_char(t3.col9, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate with instr doesn't allow index access. So you are ending with full table scan of T3.
You may formulate the predicate diferently as:

```
 where col1 in (to_date('27.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('10.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('23.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('01.08.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')) or
  col2 in (to_date('27.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('10.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('23.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('01.08.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')) or
  col3 in (to_date('27.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('10.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('23.07.2015','dd.mm.yyyy'),
           to_date('01.08.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')) or
 .... -- etc for columns col3 - col9
```

**If** the table T3 is large and the predicate above selectes only few records, you may profite with defining indexes on col1 to col9

```
 create index t3_ix1 on t3(col1);
 create index t3_ix2 on t3(col2);
 ....
```

The possible execution plan will perform 9 * 3 (columns * values) INDEX RANGE SCAN and BITMAP CONVERSION to get the OR result. So for realy huge T3 the 27 index range scan will be better that FULL SCAN an dyou will **speed up**; but it depends on your data...

Comment: I will try now. Also what about parallel, Do you know what is different parallel(t3, 8) and parallel(t3, 16) ?

Comment: @junior to be able to comment further please post following information: size of the table T3; how many rows does the query return; elapsed time of the query and preferable the execution plan.

Comment: T3 about 500K records. I tried your first recommendation, it effected really good. Also there is a word in query like that `select /*+ parallel(t3,8) */ t3` What does 8 value mean? For example if i try 16 then what would i have done?

Comment: @junior [parallel hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51120) was used to optimize the _FULL TABLE SCAN_ access to the T3 table. (You scan in 8 or 16 parallel threads). If the filter return only few rows (you didn't tell how much) the index access will be fine and you may remove the hint. Also check if there are indexes in T1.col1 and T2.col3, so you may deploy _NESTED LOOP_ join.

Comment: return count from T3 about 4K records. Can you give a simple example how can i integrate NESTED LOOP to my query. Also i checked there is no index in T3

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an Oracle instance to test, but `OR` conditions almost always slow down execution as does calling `instr` multiple times.  Try doing one large concatenation and searching for the value in there.  You'll notice I added a '~' to make sure you didn't get a match from data due to the concatenation:

```
select  t3.*
  from  table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
 where  t1.col1 = t2.col2 
   and  t2.col3 = t3.col4
   and  instr(l_string,
         (':' || to_char(t3.col1, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col2, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col3, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col4, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col5, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col6, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col7, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col8, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':' ||
         '~:' || to_char(t3.col9, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ':') > 0
```

I would explore other options, but without more information that's all I can offer.